# Can I customise the google sign in pop up in flutter to filter out emails?

Tags: flutter, dart, popup, google-signin, customising

I want to show only the email ids of my organisation in the google sign-in pop-up. Is there a way to remove all the other email ids except for the organisation email ids from the UI of the pop-up?

[image: I want to show only the organisation email id here, and remove other email ids from this pop-up]

Comment: no thats the list of emails the user signed in with on their machine

Comment: Okay. I was wondering if there was a way we could show only the oraganization email ids which were logged in instead of all the logged-in email ids. Thank you!